# URLSession dataTask -- Could not connect to the server

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I'm trying to load data from the following url:: https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

**Function**

```
func download() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    self.downloadTask = self.session.dataTask(with: self.url)                
    self.downloadTask.resume()
}
```

**Delegates**

```
// NOT GETTING CALLED
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}

// NOT GETTING CALLED
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    self.completion(self, data)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    print(error)
   // THIS IS GETTING CALLED WITH ERROR: Could not connect to the server. FULL ERROR BELOW.
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
    print(error)
}
```

**Full Error**

> (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 \"Could not connect to the
>   server.\" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0658cc0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 \"(null)\"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.})

**Below is the ATS configuration**

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated!

> **Note** The above URL works in Chrome but fails to load in Safari

Comment: I just tried to open the video on my browser and seems like their server is lagging right now. try using another website

Comment: I too tried that. It's opening in Chrome, but fails in Safari.

Comment: is the issue resolved now?